# Spring Data Repository error on startup after dependencies update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We are updating the project dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.3 (hibernate-core:5.6.10)` to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.0 (hibernate-core:6.2.2)` and we get the following error on application startup.

`org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: AcademicEdition`

Associated with this exception

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List CourseProfessorRepository.findByEditionId(java.lang.Long); Unable to locate persister: AcademicEdition`

But this doesn't make sense because the `AcademicEdition` mapped superclass is not directly related to the `CourseProfessor` entity class.

### Repository

The `CourseProfessorRepository` manage the  `CourseProfessor` entity.

```
public interface CourseProfessorRepository extends EditionProfessorRepository<CourseProfessor> {

    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, value = "course-professor")
    List<CourseProfessor> findByEditionId(Long editionId);

}
```

There is a base repository

```
@NoRepositoryBean  
public interface EditionProfessorRepository<E extends EditionProfessor<?>> extends JpaRepository<E, EditionProfessorId> {  
List<E> findByEditionId(Long editionId);  
}
```

### Entity

The `CourseProfessor` class represents the relation between a `Professor` and a `CourseEdition`.

```
public final class CourseProfessor extends EditionProfessor<CourseEdition> {
}
```

This relation is represented by the `EditionProfessor` generic class. The `edition` property is generic and it type is declared as `CourseEdition` in `CourseProfessor` subclass.

[image]

### Posible problem

The `CourseEdition` entity class extends from `ImprovingEdition` and not from `AcademicEdition`.

[image]

Why is the relation between `AcademicEdition` and `CourseProfessorRepository` in the error. How can we fix this.